# Selenium webdriver Wait method with dependency injection

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver, wait

Long story short: I'm working on a framework that has generic wait methods which deal with objects. Typically per page, you need to have the `Wait` function in the `{Area}Page` class and there it needs to find the optimal set of object(s) which will confidently tell if all the page objects are loaded. All of this depends on how much effort has gone into managing how objects are loaded on a page, i.e. the item at the bottom of the page is not necessarily the last object to be loaded.

In the framework itself, I want to change the functions like `WaitById` to simply `WaitTillDisplayed` or something similar and use injection to identify the object, i.e. the function should not determine how the object is identified (I think I should use dependency injection). I'm not sure on how to get that done. Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this done? Thanks.

```
   public static void WaitForPageLoad(string browserTitle)
   {
        Containers.LogStep logStep = new Containers.LogStep();

        try
        {
            string checkString = "";
            DefaultWait<string> wait = new DefaultWait<string>(checkString);
            wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10); // .FromMinutes(1);
            wait.PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250);

            Func<string, bool> waiter = new Func<string, bool>((string ele) 
     =>
            {
                String findTitle = Browser.Title;
                if (findTitle.Contains(browserTitle))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
            wait.Until(waiter);

            logStep.Source = "WaitForPageLoad";
            logStep.ElementName = browserTitle;
            logStep.Action = "Wait Page";
            logStep.Data = "";

            logStep.Friendly = String.Concat("Wait for Page with title \"", 
          browserTitle, "\" to load");
            logStep.Screenshot = Capture();

            logStep.Result = Reporting.Pass;
            Reporting.LogStep(logStep);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logStep.Friendly = e.Message.ToString();
            logStep.Result = Reporting.Fail;
            Reporting.LogStep(logStep);
        }
    }

    public static void WaitForDialogLoad(IWebElement dialog, string 
    dialogTitle)
    {
        Containers.LogStep logStep = new Containers.LogStep();
        try
        {
            string checkString = "";
            DefaultWait<string> wait = new DefaultWait<string>(checkString);
            wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10); // .FromMinutes(1);
            wait.PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250);

            Func<string, bool> waiter = new Func<string, bool>((string ele) 
    =>
            {
                String findTitle = dialog.Text.ToString();
                if (findTitle.Contains(dialogTitle))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
            wait.Until(waiter);

            logStep.Source = "WaitForDialogLoad";
            logStep.ElementName = dialogTitle;
            logStep.Action = "Wait Dialog";
            logStep.Data = "";

            logStep.Friendly = String.Concat("Wait for Dialog with title 
     \"", dialogTitle, "\" to load");
            logStep.Screenshot = Capture();

            logStep.Result = Reporting.Pass; 
            Reporting.LogStep(logStep);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logStep.Friendly = e.Message.ToString();
            logStep.Result = Reporting.Fail;
            Reporting.LogStep(logStep);
        }
    }

    public static void WaitByClassName(string elementName, string findBy)
    {
        Containers.LogStep logStep = new Containers.LogStep();
        try
        {
            IWebElement element = 
  Browser.GetDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName(findBy));
            int maxWait = 10000;
            int counter = 0;

            while (element == null && counter < maxWait)
            {
                element = 
  Browser.GetDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName(findBy));
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                counter += 500;
            }

            logStep.Source = "WaitByClassName";
            logStep.ElementName = elementName; // element.GetLogicalName();
            logStep.Action = "Displayed";
            logStep.Data = element.Displayed.ToString();

            logStep.Friendly = "Wait for \"" + logStep.ElementName + "\" to 
  be displayed on page";

            logStep.Result = Reporting.Pass;
            Reporting.LogStep(logStep);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logStep.Friendly = e.Message.ToString();
            logStep.Result = Reporting.Fail;
            Reporting.LogStep(logStep);
        }
    }
    public static void WaitById(string elementName, string findBy)
    {
        Containers.LogStep logStep = new Containers.LogStep();
        try
        {
            IWebElement element = 
  Browser.GetDriver.FindElement(By.Id(findBy));
            int maxWait = 10000;
            int counter = 0;

            while (element == null && counter < maxWait)
            {
                element = Browser.GetDriver.FindElement(By.Id(findBy));
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                counter += 500;
            }

            logStep.Source = "WaitById";
            logStep.ElementName = elementName;
            logStep.Action = "Displayed";
            logStep.Data = element.Displayed.ToString();

            logStep.Friendly = "Wait for \"" + logStep.ElementName + "\" to 
be displayed on page";

            logStep.Result = Reporting.Pass;
            Reporting.LogStep(logStep);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logStep.Friendly = e.Message.ToString();
            logStep.Result = Reporting.Fail;
            Reporting.LogStep(logStep);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `By` locator as argument to the method instead of the string.

```
public static void WaitTillDisplayed(string elementName,  By locator)
{
    Containers.LogStep logStep = new Containers.LogStep();
    try
    {
        IWebElement element = Browser.GetDriver.FindElement(locator); // Updated By variable instead of string
        int maxWait = 10000;
        int counter = 0;

        while (element == null && counter < maxWait)
        {
            element = Browser.GetDriver.FindElement(locator); // Updated By variable instead of string
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            counter += 500;
        }

        logStep.Source = "WaitById";
        logStep.ElementName = elementName;
        logStep.Action = "Displayed";
        logStep.Data = element.Displayed.ToString();

        logStep.Friendly = "Wait for \"" + logStep.ElementName + "\" to be displayed on page";

        logStep.Result = Reporting.Pass;
        Reporting.LogStep(logStep);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logStep.Friendly = e.Message.ToString();
        logStep.Result = Reporting.Fail;
        Reporting.LogStep(logStep);
    }

}
```

So now you can call this method with any locator you wish:

```
WaitTillDisplayed("loginTextBox", By.id("login"));

 // OR

WaitTillDisplayed("loginTextBox", By.className("txt"));

 // OR

WaitTillDisplayed("loginTextBox", By.xpath("//input[0]"));
```

Is that what you wanted?